# Firebase Firestore wait for update to complete (js web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the below I get a doc, update it, then try to use the data from the update, however `undefined` is logged. Why is this and how can wait to successfully fetch the new data from the doc.

```
db.collection("collection").doc("docid").get().then(doc =>
  doc.ref.update({ message: "hello" }).then(() => console.log(doc.data().message));
)
```

I am using the Javascript Web version for firebase.

Comment: It's not possible to explain this with only the line of code you've given.  We don't know what `doc` is, where it came from, and what you intend to do with it.  In total, it's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added some more context and explanation - does it make sense now?

Comment: Well, your console log is only going to happen after the update completes.  It's not clear to me why you want to log the value of `doc.data().message` or what you expect it to contain other than undefined.

Comment: @DougStevenson I want to do some more work with the doc object, including render UI with it's `doc.data()`. I've excluded that stuff as it didn't seem relevant to the question and was trying to keep it as minimal as possible. Since the console log is going to happen after the update completes, I was expecting it to log the message of "hello".

Comment: `doc` in your case is a `DocumentSnapshot`, and as the name suggests it is a snapshot of the document taken at a given time. So when you update the doc after the snapshot got created this will not be updated in `doc`. You would need to wait for the update to finish, and fetch another `DocumentSnapshot`. See my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you want to wait for the update to complete before continuing with the code. Calling `update` on a `DocumentReference` returns a promise that resolves to a `WriteResult`. You could simply wait for the promise to resolve and then continue with the code:

```js
// store DocumentReference
const docRef = db.collection("collection").doc("docid");

// update document
docRef.update({ message: "hello" }).then(writeResult => {

  // wait for update to complete and display WriteResult
  console.log(writeResult);

  // to prove that update is finished, fetch the same document from firestore
  return docRef.get();

}).then(documentSnapshot => {
  console.log(documentSnapshot.id, "=>", documentSnapshot.data()); 
  // => "docid => { message: 'hello'}"
})
```

**SAME SOLUTION WITH ASYNC AWAIT SYNTAX**

```js
// store DocumentReference
const docRef = db.collection("collection").doc("docid");

// update document + wait for completing, then display write result
const writeResult = await docRef.update({ message: "hello" });
console.log(writeResult);

// to prove that update is finished, fetch the same document from firestore
// and display document content
const documentSnapshot = await docRef.get();
console.log(documentSnapshot.id, "=>", documentSnapshot.data()); 
// => "docid => { message: 'hello'}"
```